# Accessing Git from Assembla using SSH+RSA

Tags: 14.04, ssh, repository, git

I have just created a repository on Assembla using a Git repository and I have followed their "Getting started with Git" page :

1. I validated my git `user.email` and `user.name`. Since I'm also using the account on Github, the `user.name` are *slightly* different between the two accounts. (Can this be an issue?)
2. I generated my keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "<email address>"`. Both email addresses are the same for Github and Assembla. **Edit**: and uploaded the `.pub` file into my Assembla profile.
3. Added the remote repository with `git remote add origin git@git.assembla.com:<repository name>`
4. Made a commit and pushed to `remote master`.

The usual RSA asked me to accept and confirm the certificate, then Ubuntu warned me that the key is locked. I tried my `sudo` password, my Assembla password... nothing works; I cannot have access to the remote repository.

What's going on?

Comment: Did you upload your ssh key to your Assembla profile?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that, but yes.

Comment: "then Ubuntu warned me that the key is locked." Could you please include the *exact* error message you are seeing? It should ask for the passphrase you set on the SSH key generated (`ssh-keygen` command you used). This is not about a user/sudo password. Please also include the output of `ssh-add -l`. These are the SSH identities (keys) managed by your SSH *agent*. They are given precendence over the local keys installed, if they are present in the agent. If you require to not load these keys for your remote host, you can disable them in the SSH (user) config. (but just first provide more info)

Comment: @gertvdijk the "warned me that the key is locked" part refers to Ubuntu popping up the modal dialog. ... but, while writing this comment, I realized that `ssh-keygen` *did* asked me for a passphrase. Entering that passphrase into the dialog solve it. I don't recall doing that for the RSA keys I generated for Github... Must be Monday.

Answer (score 1):

As a legacy to my Monday clumsiness, the answer is as dumb as :

The command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "<email address>"` asks for a passphrase. If a value is set, that passphrase is the value that must be entered to "unlock" the key.

Now facepalm, everybody!

[image]